# What's the quicker or more efficient in Javascript a no op or if statement?

Tags: javascript

I use this :

```
function (foo){
  foo = foo || function () { };
  foo();
  //do some thing
}
```

but could use the more traditional:

```
function (foo){
  if(typeof foo === 'function'){
    foo(); 
  }
  //do some thing
}
```

** Amended as per vivek_nk's comment.

I think the first example is better to read but which one is more efficient when it's compiled in the various javascript compilers?

Comment: Why don't you [test](http://jsperf.com/) yourself?

Comment: Are they even semantically equivalent?!

Comment: Micro optimisation. Go spend an hour profiling this to find an answer. Then calculate how many months of improved performance it will take to recover the time you've spent on the exercise.

Comment: You can just `foo && foo();` (readability is subjective).

Comment: Why should this be marked down or closed? I could test this myself but why would I if someone else has already done this!? 
Micro optimisation is important in some projects. 

I'm interested to know how this gets compiled - rather than investigating manually, I was hoping someone might have an intelligent answer but it appears some people on SO are too obnoxious to give a decent answer or just click back!

Comment: @MikeW - surely the comments on the answers already given suggest that there is enough discussion around my question for this not to be put on hold!

Answer (score 2):

Both are different.

### Why?

Because first one checks whether the foo is `null` or `undefined` or `false` or `0` or `""` or `NaN`

Second one checks only for the `undefined`.

Personally I feel you should be using first one since it checks for various things, and assigns in a single line of code and is more readable.

Comment: The objective of both examples is the same.

Comment: First one also checks for `0` and empty string.

Comment: Oh, and `NaN`... anything that's falsy.

Answer (score 1):

Both these ways are wrong. I see u want to call another function, before doing 'something'..
So check if it is function, not just if it is not undefined.

```
function (foo){
  //we check of type function 
  //because if string is passed ur condition wont work
  if(typeof foo == "function"){
    foo(); 
  }
  //do some thing
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the first one?

Comment: you are creating unnecessary function objects. Instead you can use foo && foo(); as suggested by @Salman above in comments, which is shorter than the same what i have given you for understanding.